# Probability of generating the symmetric group

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability, co.combinatorics

The statement is simple:

What is the probability that a set of n-1 transpositions generates the symmetric group, $S_n$?

The motivation is that I remembered reading that this was an open problem somewhere on the internet, and then I solved it. I'm curious to see other people's solutions, because I think it's a nice problem, and don't quite believe that it is hard enough to be open.

Comment: The motivation, "I remember reading that this was an open problem somewhere on the internet" does not strike one as very compelling. 
Isn't it true that $n-1$ transpositions, viewed as edges of a graph on $n$ vertices, generate $S_n$ if and only if the graph is a tree? So it's a question of tree enumeration. 

Comment: Good point. How does it look like translating the bijection it terms of Pruefer sequences? (I fear it doesn't add much to the picture though)

Comment: I also remember that this "open problem" was one of the questions of the university entrance examination of a friend of mine.

Comment: So I thought as well. I wonder what the actual statement was, or whether I had dreamt it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A solution (assuming that all transpositions are distinct and are choosen uniformly among all
${n\choose 2}$ possible transpositions) can be given as follows:

A set of $n-1$ transpositions $(a_1,b_1),\dots,(a_{n-1},b_{n-1})$ on the set $\lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace$ generates the whole symmetric group
of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ if and only if the graph with vertices $\lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace$ and edges $\lbrace a_i,b_i\rbrace$ is a tree.

The probability to generate $S_n$ is thus the same as the probability to get a tree with $n$ vertices $V$ when choosing randomly
$n-1$ edges with endpoints in $V$.
By Cayley's theorem, there are $n^{n-2}$ different trees with vertices $\lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace$.
Since there are ${{n\choose 2}\choose n-1}$ different graphs with $n-1$ edges and vertices $\{1,\dots,n\}$, the 
probability is given by 
$n^{n-2}/{{{n\choose 2}\choose n-1}}$.

If repetitions are allowed, one gets $n^{n-2}/{{n\choose  2}+n-2\choose n-1}$ (assuming uniform probability for all distinct multisets).

Comment: Or very roughly $\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n$.

Comment: In the case, we take a random subset $A$ of $S_n$ with probability $p$, what is the probability which $x\in A$ condition on a number of transpositions $(a_1,b_1),\cdots, (a_m,b_m)$ with $m$ is fixed? Thanks.

Comment: @user52523 I do not understand your question. Could you reformulate it unambigously?

Comment: @RolandBacher: I am sorry for this. Let me write it in a different way. Let A be a random subset of $S_n$ and we consider the function $1_{A}(\sigma)=1$ with probability $p$ or $0$ with probability $1-p$. Now, if we choose $(a_1,b_1), \cdots, (a_m, b_m)$ for a fixed $m$, I would like to know what is the probability that $1_{A}(\sigma)=1 $ on permutations $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(a_i=b_i$ for all $i=1, \cdots, m$. I hope that it is clear now. Thanks.

Comment: @user52523 Sorry, your question is still not clear : Are $(ai,b_i)$ transpositions or simply elements of $\lbrace 1,\ldots,n\rbrace$? How do you choose $\sigma$ (uniformly?) etc? I can not read your mind and therefore your question has to be absolutely clear.

Comment: Here, $a_i, b_i$ simply elements of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $A$ is a random subset of $S_n$. Given that if you take $\sigma\in S_n$ then $P(\sigma\in A)=p$, $P(\sigma\notin A)=1-p$. I hope that it is clear now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I give up.

Comment: @RolandBacher: That's fine. Thanks for your patience.